# Getting WebException "The operation has timed out" at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() when reading images and video from amazon s3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, system.net.webexception

Here is my code to create image url :

```
List<FileName> lstFileURL = AmazonFunction.GetFileUrlList(BucketName, BucketFolderName, Time);
```

create amazons3client object :

```
private static AmazonS3Client GetS3Client()
            {
                NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

                AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client)AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
                        appConfig["AWSAccessKey"],
                        appConfig["AWSSecretKey"],
                        RegionEndpoint.USEast1
                        );
                return s3Client;
            }
```

create image url list :

```
    public static List<FileName> GetFileUrlList(string BUCKET_NAME, string name, double Time)
                {

                    List<FileName> ListImageName = new List<FileName>();
                    using (GetS3Client())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ListObjectsRequest Lor = new ListObjectsRequest()
                            {
                                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME,
                                // with Prefix is a folder Key, it will list only child of that folder
                                Prefix = name,
                                //with Delimiter is '/', it will not get folder.
                                Delimiter = "/"
                            };
                            ListObjectsResponse response1 = GetS3Client().ListObjects(Lor);



                            //ListBuckets

                            for (int i = 0; i < response1.S3Objects.Count; i++)
                            {
                                ListImageName.Add(new FileName(MakeUrl(BUCKET_NAME, response1.S3Objects[i].Key.ToString().Split('/')response1.S3Objects[i].Key.ToString().Split('/').Length - 1], Time)));

                            }


                        }
                        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Show Exception
                        }
                    }
                    return ListImageName;
                }
```

Here is my code to create video url :

```
VideoFilePath = AmazonFunction.GetFileURL(BucketName, videotitle, Time);
```

create video url :

```
        public static string GetFileURL(string BUCKET_NAME, string FILE_NAME, double TIME)
                {
                    using (GetS3Client())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            GetObjectRequest gor = new GetObjectRequest()
                            {
                                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME,
                                Key = FILE_NAME,
                            };

                            GetObjectResponse response = GetS3Client().GetObject(gor);

                            string FileURL = MakeUrl(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME, TIME);

                            return FileURL;
                        }
                        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
                        {
                            return "FileNotFound";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am getting System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out on below lines :

```
List<FileName> lstFileURL = AmazonFunction.GetFileUrlList(BucketName, BucketFolderName, Time);
VideoFilePath = AmazonFunction.GetFileURL(BucketName, videotitle, Time);
```

I am using MVC 4.

Comment: How big are these assets? HTTP itself may be timing out, if you're trying to download the entire video in one call. You may want to download it in chunks.

Comment: I am trying to create URL of video to read from amazon s3 and playing in HTML 5 player. Not downloading the whole video. And list of image URLs to display in page.

Comment: This code is working fine on development machine but when I am hosting it in server it throws this exception.

Comment: What are the details (error codes, messages) in the exception object?

Comment: Actually i am writing error log in text file. so unable to find   error code. below is the error msg and inner exception.     Error Message : A WebException with status Timeout was thrown. Inner exception : System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse()        source : AWSSDK

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below config in your web.config.

```
    <system.net>
            <defaultProxy enabled = "true" useDefaultCredentials = "true"/>
    </system.net>
```

Comment: could you add some explanation on how does in help? this will help understanding your answer to other developers as well.